# If measurement error is only for a specific group do you avoid bias by controlling for that group?

Tags: multiple-regression, econometrics, measurement-error

I am running regressions to estimate the impact of health conditions on life satisfaction.

I have read a paper that showed that there is likely to be measurement error in the self-reported health variables in that those who do not work are more likely to report health problems to justify not working.

My question is, is this a problem for my estimates? I include various dummy controls to capture employment status so do I simply control for this potentially problematic bias due to measurement error?

Or, is the bias still there in which case I guess it would be a downward bias? Does my use of panel data and fixed effects make any difference?

Comment: If people self-report that is almost surely going to be a problem. Dummy variables cannot show what does not exist in the data, because people omitted / hid it.